# Get values using good Hibernate practices

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

Good afternoon people!
I think that may be a silly question ..

I have the following code in Hibernate:

```
query = session.createQuery ("select F from Employee F where F.email =" + email);
```

Does anyone know how I can get the value of a field within this query?

Example: How would I get the name of the person (employee).

Note: I would like to use a good Hibernate practice ... I believe it is not good to repeat:

```
query = session.createQuery ("select F.person from Employee F where F.email =" + email);
```

Can you help me? :)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want to get the name of the employee, execute the query, which will return an Employee, and call getName() on the returned employee. Is that what you're asking? If you want a query that only returns the name rather than the whole employee, then do what you're doing in the second query of your question (but use a named parameter for the email). What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Hibernate 5.2:

```
String sql = "SELECT e.person FROM Employee e WHERE e.email = :email";
Query query = session.createQuery( sql )     
query.setParameter( "email", emailAddress );
List<Person> people = (List<Person>) query.getResultList();
```

In Hibernate 5.2 and beyond:

```
String sql = "SELECT e.person FROM Employee e WhERE e.email = :email";
Query query = session.createQuery( sql, Person.class );
query.setParameter( "email", emailAddress );
List<Person> people = query.getResultList();
```

With the merge of Hibernate EntityManager into Core as a part of 5.2.x+, you now get better type safe queries to avoid casting later on :).